# Laravel Eloquent Multiple 'WHERE NOT LIKE' Statements

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to filter a users list to remove any test accounts with certain email extensions.

My query:

```
User::where('email', 'NOT LIKE', '%test.com')
    ->where('email', 'NOT LIKE', '%test1.com')
    ->where('email', 'NOT LIKE', '%test2.com')
    ->where('email', 'NOT LIKE', '%test3.com')
```

I'm wondering if there's a better way to write this in one statement like whereNotIn but that doesn't seem to work. I'm looking for something like this:

```
User::whereNotLike('email', [
    '%test.com',
    '%test1.com',
    '%test2.com',
    '%test3.com',
]);
```

Comment: Not really. IN works for a list of exact matches. LIKE compares to a single pattern. You're stuck with the first notation, that's the way SQL does it. Another way is to use REGEXP to get all your use cases checked

Comment: `whereNotLike()` only accepts a single value, not an array. You can use multiple `whereNotLike()` calls, or multiple `where()` calls, but you can't really shorten it into a single one like you attempted. And that's simply because MySQL (and other SQL languages) don't have logic to support `WHERE ... NOT LIKE IN (...)`. I'd define a scope, like `public function scopeIgnoreTests()`, that simple appends this group of `WHERE` clauses as a nested `WHERE(...)` clause, and apply to any query you need it on, like `User::ignoreTests()->get()`, etc: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#query-scopes

Answer (score 4):

The only way to achieve what you want is to use regular expressions in the query.

Here's one that should catch all your use cases.

```php
$users = User::whereRaw("email NOT REGEXP '?'", ['test[0-9]*.com$'])->get();
```

Here's another one using your specific values.

```php
$endsWith = [
    'test.com$',
    'test1.com$',
    'test2.com$',
    'test3.com$',
];

$users = User::whereRaw("email NOT REGEXP '?'", [implode('|', $endsWith])->get();
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer thanks! The first option wouldn't work because not all of them are necessarily 'test[x].com' I just used that for simplicity. Using the array of specific values is perfect.